# How to write ruby erb tag in slim javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

```
javascript:
  var flash_message = '';

  - if flash.any?


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  });
```

I want use normal erb tag in javascript area generate by slim. If have flash message, set flash_message = html string generate by rails helper. But I can't use - if flash.any? in javascript: of slim.

Comment: <% if flash.any? %>, you mean like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Text interpolation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Text_interpolation):

```
var flash_message = '#{flash.any? ? flash_to_html_helper(flash) : nil}';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new with slim, everything diffirent with erb